# Undefined offset for an array in php

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$count_table = array();
foreach ($events_tab as $event) {
    if(isset($event["nature"])){
        $count_table[$event["nature"]]++;
    }

}
```

The array events_tab is like this :

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
       (
        [nature] => 300
        [id] => 100828698
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [nature] => 3001
        [id] => 100828698
    )

)
```

I get the error :  Undefined offset: 300 in this line : `$count_table[$event["nature"]]++;`. Please help me!! Thx in advance!!

Comment: `$count_table[300]` isn't set, but you're trying to increment the value that it holds..... how can you increment a value that doesn't exist?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Replace `$count_table[$event["nature"]]++;` with `isset($count_table[$event["nature"]]) ? $count_table[$event["nature"]]++ : $count_table[$event["nature"]] = 1;`

Comment: Increment the array : `$count_table`

Comment: Or even replace the whole thing with a simple: `$count_table = array_count_values(array_column($events_tab, 'nature', 'nature'));` should work with recent versions of PHP

Comment: @Gigel Do you need count each **nature** separately?

Answer (score 2):

```
$count_table = array();
foreach ($events_tab as $event) {

    if(isset($event["nature"])){
        if(!isset($count_table[$event["nature"]])){
            $count_table[$event["nature"]]=0;
        }
        $count_table[$event["nature"]]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on `$count_table` if the key is set. It should be -

```
if(isset($count_table[$event["nature"]])){
    $count_table[$event["nature"]]++;
} else {
    $count_table[$event["nature"]] = 0;
}
```